# Scalability 1-way. What does it mean?

Tags: hp-proliant, scalability, intel

I have read "Scalability: 1-way" in the specifications of a server. What does it means?

The server is :

HP ProLiant ML110 G6 TV X3430 2.40GHz 4-core 1P 1GB-U Non-hot Plug 250GB SATA LFF 300W PS

Comment: From the tags I'm guessing it's an HP Proliant of some kind. An exact model will help.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In old Compaq vernacular the number of CPU sockets was traditionally referred-to as "1-way" for single socket, "2-way" for dual socket, "4-way", etc. I suspect that you're looking at a machine with a single CPU socket.

Comment: That would make sense. It has an Intel Xeon with 4 cores, but maybe it uses only one socket. could it be? I have updated the post with the server description.